# Prove that for any $x\geq0$ and $y \ge 0$ we have: $|\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{y}| \le \sqrt{|x − y|}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, radicals, absolute-value

> Prove that for any $x\geq0$ and $y \ge 0$ we have:   $$|\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{y}|   \le \sqrt{|x − y|}.$$

$$|\sqrt(x) - \sqrt(y)|^2 \le \sqrt{|x-y|}^2$$
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \le |x-y|$$
$$x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \le |x-y|$$

How do I take the absolute value separately to prove it?

Comment: You can aways take cases:  Case 1: $x \ge y$ so $x-2\sqrt{xy} +y \le x -y$ so $2y-2\sqrt{xy}\le 2y-2\sqrt{yy}  \le 0$  and Case 2: $x <y$ then $2x-2\sqrt{xy} +y\le 2x - 2\sqrt{xx} \le 0$.  Or via symmetry you could have stated in the first step wolog y \ge x.

Comment: @fleablood why do you make $x = y$?

Comment: I didn't.  When $x \ge y$ we know $\sqrt{xy} \ge \sqrt{yy}$ and if $x < y$ we know $\sqrt{xy} \ge \sqrt{xx}$.

Comment: But I did accidently state $2x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \le 2x - 2\sqrt{xx}$ when I meant to say $2x - 2\sqrt{xy} \le 2x - 2\sqrt{xx}$.  That was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After squaring of the both sides we need to prove that 
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|^2\leq(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|$$ or
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y},$$
which is obvious:
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}.$$
Done!

Comment: How do you get $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ from $\sqrt{|x-y|}$?

Comment: @lakada I used $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. $\left(\sqrt{|x-y|}\right)^2=|x-y|=|(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})|$.

Answer (score 1):

The last inequality you have is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, that is, replacing $x$ with $y$ and vice-versa does not change the inequality. So, without loss of generality, assume $x \geq y$. You can now remove the modulus on the right, and you can continue to solve.

Comment: Solving further I get $x - \sqrt{xy} \le 0 \rightarrow x \le \sqrt{xy}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @lakada yes, that's right (you will get this when you assume $y \geq x$.

Answer (score 0):

> $$x=|x+y-y|\leq y+|x-y| \Rightarrow \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{y+|x-y|} \leq \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{|y-x|}$$
>
> $$y=|y+x-x|\leq x+|y-x| \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{|y-x|}$$

Thus $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $2$ cases:
$$\begin{align} & x<y \Rightarrow \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}<0< \sqrt{|x-y|}, \\
& x\ge y \Rightarrow \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\le \sqrt{x-y} \Rightarrow x-2\sqrt{xy}+y\le x-y \Rightarrow y\le x. \end{align}$$